# mysql setup issue on Mac system

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

I have install mysql using command brew install mysql. After that set password for root. still I am not able to login in mysql shell

```
brew install mysql
    sheetal$ mysql -uroot
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    sheetal$ mysql -uroot -p
    Enter password: 
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    sheetal$ sudo mysql -uroot -p
    Password:
    Enter password: 
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    sheetal$ mysql_secure_installation

    Securing the MySQL server deployment.

    Enter password for user root: 
    Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to consider using `sudo` here...the credentials problem is with MySQL, not your Linux installation.  Are you _sure_ that you are using the password you actually set?  If you are, then I don't have an explanation.  Maybe it didn't get set for some reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: OP is using **macOS** *not* **Linux**.

Comment: it's using MacOS@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @l'L'l Yes, I now this, but Mac OS is a fork of Linux (I think).  Anyway, my comment is still relevant for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot your password. To reset the root password, you need to start your mysql server with `--skip-grant-tables` option. This allows you to log in to your mysql console without any password.

```
$mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
$mysql
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
mysql> quit;
$mysql.server restart
```

Now you should be able to log in with your newpassword.

There're [other ways](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) to do this but I find this to be the easiest.